Connected with npm mqtt package via MQTTS - Is there any method to check the communication is encrypted with SSL cert?
I am connected to MQTTS using the node package (npm MQTT). I have followed the documentation. I am trying to confirm that the SSL certificate is in use and that the communication with the broker is indeed encrypted. I have read the documentation and the only mention of SSL is these few sentences:
In case mqtts (mqtt over tls) is required, the options object is passed through to tls.connect(). If using a self-signed certificate, set rejectUnauthorized: false. However, be cautious as this exposes you to potential man in the middle attacks and isn't recommended for production.

Therefore I have set the rejectUnauthorized to true. I am connecting but I do not know if this is sufficient to confirm that the messages are being encrypted.
I have tried to print out the client object. I went through it but there is no documentation to refer to that would let me know which part is saying that encryption is on and is indeed working as expected.
So my question is: Which part of the client object value would let me know if encryption/SSL is working OR is there any other way/method/test I can do to confirm the encryption is on?
Thank you for your kind answers and patience.

Update the question to show the code that setups up the connection, e.g the options object passed to connect().
But if you provide a mqtts:// URL for the broker then it will only connect over a secure connection.

If you want another step of verification you could use a network sniffer to (try to) look at the MQTT packets.
